# Generate random math operations from a predefined set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So as the title says is there any way to pull a math problem from a predefined set and output it to the user?

I am making this for a game. We've generated sprites for 0-9, + and - symbols.

is there anyway to generate a math problem and with their sprites attached to a gameObject? and then having answers displayed as options?thank you!

What I can think of initially is to assign values to the gameObject of each sprite then pass it to a string where the code will then solve it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is to put your sprites in a `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<char,GameObject> characters;
...
characters.Add('+', plusSignSprite);
...
```

Then you can instantiate the sprites with a string

```
int i=0;
myString = "5-2=3"; // or take is from an array of strings

foreach(char c in myString.ToCharArray()){
    Instantiate(characters[c], new Vector3(i,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
    i+=characterWidth;
}
```

Comment: I did this: Am I on the right track? I made prefabs of the sprites made by our designer. Would I be able to assign them to a value in code which I can use to solve equations?
    Dictionary<char, GameObject> characters = new Dictionary<char, GameObject>();        

        GameObject plusSignSprite = null;
        characters.Add('+', plusSignSprite);

Comment: You can do `characters.Add('+', Resources.Load<GameObject>("plusSignSprite"));` .. etc for your sprites. Make sure to put the prefabs in the Resource folder.

Comment: that's in Build\gametest\Resources right? To clarify, plusSignSprite is the name of the prefab right? Since I simply named them +,-,0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: Yes the folder is Resources and plusSignSprite is the name.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful, really new to unity, I only have small background on c# plus our teacher isn't exactly helpful.

so I added all the characters to the dictionary, how do I add the 10 equations we made(basic addition and subtraction)? I can't quite understand the second line of code you suggested to me.

Comment: You mean this `"11+2=13".ToCharArray()` ? `"11+2=13"` is just a string it can be whatever you want.

Comment: I got that part, this sounds dumb but do I have to create 10 instances of
        
    foreach(char c in "11+2=13".ToCharArray()){
    Instantiate(characters[c], new Vector3(i,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
    i+=characterWidth;
    }

or I only need to separate them with commas?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid strings. Start by generating the components of the equation say `5`, `+` and `4`. From these work out the answer `9`. Then generate the sprites and display. This will work out easier than using a string which you would need to parse. You can build more complex equations using a tree structure if needed.

Comment: hmm, I get what you mean, I don't really need complex tree structures as the game we plan to make is a children's game. This is for a school project by the way and not professional work.

Comment: how would you store a `+`

Comment: You could just use a single char `'+'`. You can have constants `PLUS 1, MINUS 2, TIMES 3, DIVIDE 4` and use an integer. You could use enums, or objects.